# How do I create event listeners for version 1.4 of Appcelerator Ti.Paint?

Tags: canvas, titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I am using Titanium SDK 4.1.0.GA and originally used version 1.2 of the Ti.Paint module for iOS. This version does not work properly on iOS 8 in the sense that the line drawn stutters.

I then upgraded the Ti.Paint module to 1.4 (currently the latest release). The line drawing on the canvas now works perfectly, but for some reason there are no event Listeners for the Ti.Paint Object, where there were in previous versions of the module.

How does one now check if someone is actually drawing on the canvas? A good example of this is if you want use to Ti.Paint to have users provide their signature and you want to validate that interaction on the Canvas occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS, trying every standard `Ti.UI.View` event from the [documentation](https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.View), I found that the view returned from `createPaintView` consistently responds to:

- `postlayout` on load
- `singletap` and `doubletap`, and
- `swipe` for most drawing gestures

I haven't seen any event documentation for PaintView. Other events did trigger, but not consistently.

Here's the code I used to test the events. Some events may be interfering with others.

```js
var Paint = require('ti.paint');
var paintView = Paint.createPaintView({
    top: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 80,
    left: 0,
    // strokeWidth (float), strokeColor (string), strokeAlpha (int, 0-255)
    strokeColor: '#0f0',
    strokeAlpha: 255,
    strokeWidth: 10,
    eraseMode: false
});
paintView.addEventListener('click', getHandler('click'));
paintView.addEventListener('dblclick', getHandler('dblclick'));
paintView.addEventListener('doubletap', getHandler('doubletap'));
paintView.addEventListener('longpress', getHandler('longpress'));
paintView.addEventListener('postlayout', getHandler('postlayout'));
paintView.addEventListener('singletap', getHandler('singletap'));
paintView.addEventListener('swipe', getHandler('swipe'));
paintView.addEventListener('touchcancel', getHandler('touchcancel'));
paintView.addEventListener('touchend', getHandler('touchend'));
paintView.addEventListener('touchmove', getHandler('touchmove'));
paintView.addEventListener('touchstart', getHandler('touchstart'));
paintView.addEventListener('twofingertap', getHandler('twofingertap'));

function getHandler(name) {
    return function() {
        console.log('event triggered:', name);
    };
}
```

Comment: Hi Joe. I can confirm that swipe, singletap and doubletap do trigger thanks. However, it will work only 99% of the time depending on how the signature is added, because swipe, as an example, triggers left, right, up, down. It doesn't trigger when drawing at an angle.